# Why do I can't to include css-file with AsseticBundle

Tags: symfony, assetic

I am a novice at Symfony, but try to create my first own project. I started project with symfony 3.4.15.

And now I have a problem with AsseticBundle. I installed it under instruction of [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html). Then I try to include css-file to my project.

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

But symfony ignores this block and I don't see it in html.

When I try this code:

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

css-file works, but realtive paths are broken in it (it is written in documentation, I know).

My config:

```
assetic:
   debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
   use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
   filters:
       cssrewrite: ~
   read_from: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public_html'
   write_to: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public_html'
```

Please, help me to decide my problem.

Comment: show the asset_url you put and also where is your ccs file, may be you are not pointing on the correct file

Comment: I added to my config (see first post) for assetic: read_from & write_to (because I haven't /web, it's /public_html on my hosting) and first way starts to work (css-file is included). But now relative paths don't work, I have errors such as: hosting_address/app_dev.php/image/background.jpg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 435ms] - This path is written in css-file, in /public_html I have symlink at src/../Resources/public/image , where this image was placed. With Fonts I have the same problem.